# How to explain being out of shape

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-choice

**1)** Please let me know in each group of the sentences, which sentence is more natural to you:

> - That guy is very out of shape.
> - That guy is in very bad shape.
> - That guy is very unfit.

---

> - He / she is an out of shape man / woman.
> - He / she is an unfit man / woman.

**2)** How can I point out to someone who is emotionally not in a good shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first set of sentences, these sound alright to me:

> That guy is very out of shape.
>   That guy is very unfit.

However, I don't interpret them as having the same meaning.

*Out of shape*, to me, means that you are not particularly fit, but doesn't necessarily mean that you are unhealthy. It could also be that your level of fitness is not what it used to be. For example, an Olympic athlete being "out of shape" will probably be in better physical condition that most of us, they just wouldn't be up to their normal level of fitness.

*Unfit*, on the other hand, means that you are unhealthy, and usually goes along with other health issues (being overweight, having high levels of cholesterol, etc.).

> That guy is in very bad shape.

I would not interpret this sentence as relating to fitness. Instead, I would use this definition of *shape* (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**shape**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shape#shape__14)
>   [WITH ADJECTIVE] The specified condition or state of someone or something:
>   "*he was in no shape to drive*"
>   "*the company came through a difficult period in excellent financial shape*"

Unless further specified, I would assume that you were referring to the person's general health, rather than their fitness – maybe they are unwell, maybe they were mugged and beaten up, perhaps they had an accident and injured themselves.

---

This sentence should be hyphenated:

> He/she is an out of shape man/woman.
>
> He/she is an out-of-shape man/woman.

You could also say:

> He is out of shape.
>   She is a woman out of shape.

Although the second is technically correct, it sounds archaic or literary.

> He/she is an unfit man/woman.

This sentence sounds fine.

---

For the second part of your question, you could use these sentences:

> He's not doing so well.
>   He's in a bad way.

These don't refer specifically to emotional health, but can he used to refer to it. These following sentences can or do refer to emotional health:

> He isn't feeling so great.
>   He's feeling under the weather.
>   He's feeling blue.

There are also specific phrases used for mental health problems. For example, a person suffering from bipolar disorder (previously called *manic depression*) alternates between being [*manic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mania) and [*depressed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depression_(mood)). Other adjectives relating to mental health include [*schizoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schizoid_personality_disorder) and [*schizophrenic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schizophrenia), among many others.

Comment: If the person who downvoted this answer could explain their reasoning, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: No matter who did that I accept your answer. Thank you very much for spending so much time to answer my mostly boring questions LMS. :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Please let me know in each group of the sentences, which sentence
>   is more natural to you:

- That guy is very out of shape. [✓]

  - This sentence is correct and understandable because "out of shape" is
    usually only used in contexts applying to fitness, especially
    physically health. (You could also use it to apply to mental health
    as well, but you'd have to modify your statement with the adverb
    'mentally'.)
- That guy is in very bad shape. [✓]

  - This is correct because it applies to both mental and physical health, regardless of context. You might need to add to or modify your statement to make sure it makes sense (in other words, make sure that others know which kind of health you mean).
- That guy is very unfit. [X]

  - This is not correct in the sense that it doesn't refer to physical health directly, which makes it hard for the reader or listener to understand what you're saying. It mostly implies that the person is 'unfit' mentally, and in a somewhat derogatory way. This is due to the fact that unfit has various connotations in different contexts. It also means "to be not suited for reproduction" [scientific], or "to be not qualified for something." In other words, it's vague.
- He / she is an out of shape man / woman. [✓]

  - This works because you are just providing description (an adjective) to a person, much like you are in the first sentence.
- He / she is an unfit man / woman. [✓]

  - This works only because it provides a little additional bit of context (the fact that you're talking about a man or woman [one which has been specified by you] makes it seem as if you're trying to describe how they are, not how they *are* - as in, you're just talking about their appearance and not passing a judgment on their character). It provides less room for misinterpretation.

> 2) How can I point out to someone who is emotionally not in a good
>   shape?

Saying they're emotionally not in good shape is fine enough, because you just want to describe their emotions and nothing else. You don't want to describe their mental state (which would be more applicable to something like mental health, a deeper subject). If you say they don't feel well, you could be implying that they're sick (such as with something like the flu). So just stick to phrases like: "They're fine today," or "They're in a good mood today," or "They're upset." They're non-specific and refer more to emotions than emotional state. If you wanted to use a phrase related to the concept of "mental fitness" as discussed above, you could just comment on their lack of emotional control or attentiveness. You could say: "They really don't know their own emotions well," or "He doesn't know how to show empathy when I need it," or something like that.